# how to store null values (NA) for empty fields in database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, null

I have a  website which has a lot of different fields. Some of the fields are optional while some are mandatory. i want to store (NA) in DB for empty values. is this possible?

Comment: Yes, but why don't save null and just display na?

Comment: Ah.. That is supposed to be the most difficult task in this world.. I guess there is no work around on this topic.. probably there is a field which can be set to null by default.. hope you succeed and save the mankind

Comment: ya i want to display na only

Comment: @sabarish I have an answer for the question you just deleted. Ask in a different way man. I can help you. Make sure you give the HTML of the `SELECT` too.

Comment: do u ave any idea about how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `default` value as **`NA`** for the respected columns. So when the value not comes then default will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Default the values that are null. ie Age defaults to 0

Answer (score 0):

Set the default value as Null for the respective field. Try using PHPMyAdmin or any MySQL tool to do the same or write SQL Query

Answer (score 0):

I would save the empty value as NULL, and handle it from the javascript.

`NULL`=empty so it is essentially what you need.

`NA`=not applicable which is conceptually something different.

Unless your columns are of character type, so the value `NA` could be the default one, but from a semantic perspective it wouldn't mean anything..

I hope this helps.